# Riemann curvature tensor, unique surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Does the Riemann curvature tensor determine a unique surface? If I have a certain Riemann curvature tensor does it mean that only one surface has that kind of curvature? Sorry if I'm not clear enough...

Comment: Some good discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100281/does-the-curvature-determine-the-metric

Answer (score 1):

No. The simplest example is the family of tori. For each fixed $a,b$, there is a metric $a \mathrm{d}x^2 + b\mathrm{d}y^2$ on the torus $\mathbb{T}^2 = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$. All of these metrics are flat with the Riemann curvature tensor vanishing identically. The underlying manifolds are the same one, so they are obviously all diffeomorphic. But for different choices of $a,b$, the manifolds are not isometric.